# Split dataset into 2 part using extra train column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

I have total 132 rows in df dataset. If I use the following code, it gives me a random number of "True" value in "train" column. Sometimes 46 or sometimes 50 but I want to make it exactly 53 **"True"** value and 79 **"False"** value in the **"train"** column.

```
train_test_per = 60/100.0
df['train'] = np.random.rand(len(df)) < train_test_per
```

[image]

What should be the condition that I have to use here `df['train'] = "condition"`

It would be a great pleasure if someone help me. I have tried to solve but as I am new I couldn't find the proper solution.

If any information is missing please let me know.

Comment: Please copy/paste the text data instead of picture.

Comment: I have a dataset without "train" column. And I want to add "train" column in my dataset where some values of "train" column will be True and others are false.

Comment: can you hard code "train" for  first 53 as true and last 79 as false. Why you need an equation.

Comment: which test I have to copy paste can you please mention?

Comment: thanks everyone. I found my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use pandas' `sample` as you already have:

```
df['train'] = False
df.loc[df.sample(n=53).index, 'train'] = True
```

**Option 2**: `np.random.choice`:

```
train_idx = np.random.choice(df.index, size=53, replace=False)

df['train'] = False
df.loc[train_idx, 'train'] = True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

true_false = [True if x < 53 else False for x in range(100)]
random.shuffle(true_false)
df["train"] = pd.Series(true_false)
```

EDIT: Quang Hoang reply is way better than mine. I leave mine as an alternative solution.

Comment: thanks a lot. found my answer. again thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Another (ugly) way to do this could be:

```py
for i in range (0, numberOfTrues):
    df.at[np.random.rand(len(df)), 'train'] = True

df2 = df.loc[df['train'] == True]
df1 = df.loc[df['train'] != True]

for i in range (0, df1.shape[0]):
    df1['train'] = True

dfs = [df1, df2]
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Good Luck!